# Code renders in browser but errors in the IBM Notes client

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have two computed fields and want update them.  It works great in the browser, but the IBM Notes client gives an error.

Here is the code:

```
var Admin = @DbColumn("", "GoreAdmins", 1);
   var AdminBackup = @DbColumn("", "GoreAdmins", 2);
   if (Admin && typeof Admin == "string") Admin = new Array(Admin); 
   if (AdminBackup && typeof AdminBackup == "string") AdminBackup = new   Array(AdminBackup); 
   if (document1.isNewNote()) {
       document1.setValue("Admin", Admin);
       document1.setValue("AdminBackup", AdminBackup);
   };
```

I get the error on this line:
`document1.setValue("Admin", Admin);`

Comment: And what error do you get?

Comment: Please re-open this question. The answer below is the correct explanation. It is a misunderstanding of coding conventions, not a question seeking debugging help. The request to put it on hold is a misunderstanding of the platform, technology and explainable causes.

Comment: This is a legit question on the XPages platform. Needs to be reopened.

Comment: Agreed.  This is a perfectly valid question to anyone using XPages Technology.  This should not be on hold and needs to be reopened.

Answer (score 7):

The first parameter for `@DbColumn()` and `@DbLookup` needs to be the database, easiest done with `@DbName()`. The method of passing a blank string won't work in XPiNC. It's standard for Notes Client development, works for XPages on a browser but is bad practice for this very reason.